# Hide the interactions section in pandas profiling report in html

Tags: pandas, pandas-profiling

I already tried hiding the correlations, missing_values and sample values. Now i'm trying to hide the interactions but i am not able to find the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.4+ offers a *minimal mode* that you can activate via a flag parameter:

[Link to documentation](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/index.html#large-datasets)

> Version 2.4 introduces minimal mode. This is a default configuration that disables expensive computations (such as correlations and dynamic binning).

```
profile = ProfileReport(large_dataset, minimal=True)
profile.to_file("output.html")
```

Maybe this fits your needs.

EDIT:
You can also configure the output html more fine-grained via [configuration options](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/rtd/pages/advanced_usage.html#advanced-usage) or by loading a written [configuration file](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/rtd/pages/advanced_usage.html#using-a-custom-configuration-file)

This should do the trick, if i understand your question correctly:

```
r = ProfileReport(data_set, interactions=None)
```

Comment: Yes..its working to hide all expensive computations..but i need to hide only a specific computation

Comment: Just edited my answer, see if that helps. :)